# Trying to execute a function using a timer but the compiler says the function is unused

Tags: erlang

I was trying to execute a function a few seconds in the future by using `timer:apply_after()` but when I tried to compile the module it threw an error.

For example, say I have a module with two functions - one that prints an age, and another that uses a `timer` to execute it at a future time.

```
-module(test).
-export([main/0]).

print_age(Age) ->
  io:format("Your age: ~p~n", [Age]).

main() ->
  timer:apply_after(2000, test, print_age, [20]).
```

When I compile the module, I get:

```
> c(test).
test.erl:4: Warning: function print_age/1 is unused
{ok,test}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there's nothing in the [timer docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html) to indicate it, the function must be exported in order for the `timer` to execute it:

```
-module(test).
-export([main/0, print_age/1]).

print_age(Age) ->
  io:format("Your age: ~p~n", [Age]).

main() ->
  timer:apply_after(2000, test, print_age, [20]).
```

One *could* get around the compiler error by adding `-compile({nowarn_unused_function, {print_age,1}}).` to the top of the module, but then it'll turn into a runtime error when the timer attempts to execute the function:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Jun-2018::13:37:14 ===
Error in process <0.89.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{test,print_age,[20],[]}]}
```

I don't know all the inner details of how `timer` works, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25056598/301857) indicates that it's running in a `gen_server` in a separate process.

> The timer module is a standard gen_server running in a separate process. All the function in the timer module are public interfaces that execute a hidden gen_server:call or gen_server:cast to the timer server. This is a common usage to hide the internal of a server and allow further evolutions without impact on existing applications.

It makes sense I guess, since the current process must be able to continue executing code, and which function to execute must be stored safely somewhere until the delay is passed. And since one module can only access a function in another module if it's been exported, the function to execute must be exported too.